# Delete an element from numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working with `numpy array` as follows:

```
  input_series =  ['BUY' 'SELL' 'BUY' 'SELL' 'BUY' 'SELL' 'SELL' 'SELL' 'BUY' 'SELL' nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

I am searching for particular values in array and if element exist then delete

I have done this as follows:

```
delete_indices = list()
val = ['BUY','SELL','No','YES']
found_index = np.where(lowercase_series_nparray == val)                                                
delete_indices.append(found_index)
```

`delete_indices` getting as follows:

```
[(array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([0, 2, 4, 8], dtype=int64),), (array([1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),)]
```

Aftre that I am trying to delete with :

```
new_output_series = numpy.delete(input_series, delete_indices)
```

But getting error as `setting an array element with a sequence.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below statement gives you the indexes you need:

```
 found_index = np.in1d(input_series, val).nonzero()[0]
```

and then:

```
 new_array = numpy.delete(input_series, found_index)
```

Answer (score 5):

If from an array like this:

```
input_series = np.array(['BUY', 'a', 'b', 'SELL', 'YES', 'SELL', 'No', 'c', 'd', 'SELL'])
```

you want to remove these elements:

```
['BUY','SELL','No','YES']
```

Just set these as an array:

```
val = np.array(['BUY','SELL','No','YES'])
```

and then:

```
new_output_series = np.setdiff1d(input_series,val)
```

Output:

```
 ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd']
```